# powershell: automatic form login

Tags: powershell

OK, so i have some trouble getting my script to interact with the HTML form on the login page, which i want it to access.

right now, the website starts up with a page that says "sign up" or "login" and i have gotten it to click the login button, which then prompts you to the form page, where you fill in your username and your password, press the login button, and then you get access to the webpage from where you can do whatever on the page.

my problem is that no matter what i try, from other sources on the web, it just won't do anything further than get to the form page. It doesn't wanna fill the username into the input field, it doesn't wanna do anything with the password field, and it doesn't even wanna click the button input, no matter what i've tried.

[image: the image of the webpage upon which i am stuck.]

[image: the source code of the webpage upon which i am stuck]

I can only get a screenshot of the code, since it is taken from the source code of the webpage, and i could not copy any of it.

```
$ie = New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application
$FormElementsequestURI = 'https://itd-skp.sde.dk'

$ie.visible = $true
$ie.Silent  = $true
$ie.navigate($FormElementsequestURI)

while($ie.readystate -ne 4) {start-sleep -milliseconds 100}

$doc        = $ie.Document
$doc.links[1].click()

while($.ie.readystate -ne 4) {start-sleep -milliseconds 100}

#$ie.document.getElementsById("username").value = "mike2121@edu.sde.dk"
$ie.button.click() 


this is my script. i've tried with:
Doc.Documents.getElementsById
Doc.Documents.GetElementsByTag
$ie.docuements.GetElementsByTag
$ie.documents.getElementsById
```

none of these has worked, and i am honestly at a loss. i gave up on the form input field, and tried to atleast get it to click, but nothing seemed to work, so i have turned to the stackoverflow gods for guidance.

In the end, my goal is, that i want it to, after it has accessed the HTML login form, then it should fill in the respective input fields with my username and password, then click the login submit button to login. I have been struggling with this for the past 4 days without success and i am close to giving up, honestly.

Help me, benevolent gods!

Comment: Ok, i just succeeded in actually getting the form to be filled out, but i still can't get it to click the button, and im not sure why.

the code for which made the form field filling succeed was:



$form = $ie.document.forms[0]
$inputs = $form.GetElementsByTagName("input")
($inputs | where {$_.name -eq "username"}).value = $user
($inputs | where {$_.name -eq "password"}).value = $pass
($inputs | where {$_.name -eq "Button"}).Click()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer through 3 different posts on other forums, which ended up solving my problem.

The first was for the input fields, which was:

```
$form = $ie.document.forms[0]
$inputs = $form.GetElementsByTagName("input")
($inputs | where {$_.name -eq "username"}).value = $user
($inputs | where {$_.name -eq "password"}).value = $pass
```

this inputs the information given in the variables for $user and $pass into the respective input fields.

and for the code for the button click, the solution was:

```
$button = $ie.document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]
$button.click()
```

All this combined was enough to in the end, fix my problem and granted me access unto the site.

Hope i explained it well enough for if someone who has the same problems as me comes around, he/she will get some help from this